# Async task gets loaded in background but fails to display in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have the  following code-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyClass extends Activity 
{
private static final int SLEEP_TIME= 30*10; 
    //that corresponds to ~30sec 

Button mbtn;
String ipa[]=new String[10];
MyTask objMyTask;

//intialise some 10 IP Adrresses
//intialise other required variables

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_btn);

    mbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(View v) 
         {

        objMyTask = new MyTask();
        objMyTask.execute();

        // (*) At this point loop starts to run 
        & Async task starts executing, but it fails to 
       display till the loop ends, although it runs

        // FOR LOOP 1

         for(int c=1; c<=10; c++)
          { 

           String rec1 = ping(ipa[c]); 

           if( some condition involving rec1 )
           {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            " Ping Successfull ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

           else
           {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            " Pinging Failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
               }
         }

      }
   );
     }

public String ping(String ip_addrs) 
{   


 //code to check whether ip_addrs is reachable

       return str;

    }

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    Dialog dialog;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextView tvLoading,tvPer;
    Button btnCancel;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
      {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new Dialog(Display.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        // inherit other components


        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                objMyTask.cancel(true);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
      }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
         {


        //FOR LOOP 2
        for (int i = 1; i <100; i++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                break;
            } else {
                //System.out.println(i);
                publishProgress(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
      }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) 
             {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        tvLoading.setText("Loading...  " + values[0] + " %");
        tvPer.setText(values[0]+" %");

     }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
             {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        dialog.dismiss();

        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Display.this)
                .create();

        alert.setTitle("Completed!!!");
        alert.setMessage("Your Task is Completed SuccessFully!!!");
        alert.setButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        alert.show();
        }
          }
  }   //End of main class
```

**P.S:** Assume ~10 second is required to complete the entire For loop 1.

(*) 
When I run this code, Fisrt 10 seconds phone remains freezed, and from 11th second second Progress bar starts displaying till 30th second, at this point in time, Prg.Bar has already covered 33%(i.e. 10 seconds)

So, why does Progress Bar doesnot " **Display** "(although it runs) soon its executed, but starts displaying after the loop is completed.(Also note, even the toasts get displayed after 10 seconds).

Kindly someone tell what's wrong in this code, where am I going wrong, and how do I **rectify to make ProgressBar to display simultaneously while the for loop 1 is running**

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: may be loop 1 is using the UI thread heavily, so it lags the UI.. create a new thread for that loop and check once again.

Comment: @Droid - I tried modifying the code by inserting "FOR LOOP 1" within a  **New thread**, but on button click the APP is exiting. What could be the other alternatives ?

Comment: can u post your logcat error when you use the thread

Comment: @Droid - I modified code as below '**new Thread() { public void run() { //FOR LOOP 1 }}.start();**' & LOG CAT ERROR is as below

Comment: @Droid - FATAL EXCEPTION : ` Thread- 5173
java.lang.RuntimeException: can't createhandler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at anroid.widget.Toast$TN.<init>
at anroid.widget.Toast.<init>
at anroid.widget.Toast.makeText ` _I even tried putting FOR LOOP1 inside another ASYNC Task but, this time APP did not exit, rather UI   freezeed till loop gets over(same problem mentioned earlier)_

Comment: are you creating the Toast In UIThread or other thread?

Comment: @Droid - I have put Toast within FOR LOOP 1 which is within **new Thread** Also I had started the thread within the onClickListener.

Comment: make your TOAST IN UITHREAD

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html see this link

Comment: Though I modified code as-  `**if(some codition){ func1();} else { func2();}** ` within for loop. So that func1 and 2 bodies has toasts, which has definitions within UI thread. Still app exists